# How can I run Secure Connector for Linux on Power

Tags: linux, ibm-cloud

Is cast iron secure connector supported for Linux@Power?

I'm creating an app in Bluemix with a cloud integration servcie to connect to a legacy system (like linux on power).

I manage to install the connector but when I run the start command it crashes (./runclient_osgi.sh start).

Switching to Linux@Intel it works fine and I can move on to create the enterprise API and connect my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have come out with a new version of Secure Connector.  It is now called Secure Gateway.  The client that you need to install is actually a Docker container.  The Docker container is the client/connector to allow the secure connector from Bluemix back to your network.

The only requirement is the ability to run Docker.

Check out [this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/d-docker-on-power-linux-platform/) for how to get Docker up on and running on Power on Linux.